# What's the difference of HTTP Programming and Socket Programming?

Tags: sockets, http

What's the difference of HTTP Programming and Socket Programming?

I see at [difference between socket programming and Http programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108139/difference-between-socket-programming-and-http-programming)
But I still don't get the differences, can anyone help please?

Comment: The question you link above contains a good answer. If you ask for something else then pleas reformulate the question. I think that you can hardly get better answer than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108139/difference-between-socket-programming-and-http-programming to the same question.

Comment: Yeah.. I got the differences after I read it carefully. Thank you for your suggestion.